# What is the best way to design a punishment for men for introducing original sin into humanity?

Tags: magic, religion

In the bible creation story, Eve was manipulated by Satan into eating from the tree of life and then tempted Adam into sin. As punishment for helping introduce original sin into the world, God declared that she would bleed every month and that her female offspring will experience great pain during childbirth. Since myths are used by society to explain the world around them, I would like to do an equivalent story in which it was man who first sinned and was punished for it in some way.

God made man and woman separately, with woman being made first. He then gave them the ability to access magic as a gift to show his favor.This magic was slow, complex, and ritualized. However, it was very powerful, able to shape the world to suit their image. Both man and woman set out creating the animal and plant species of the world, naming them, and then basically designing the world around them. However, man committed some vile act that created much calamity into the world and became responsible for introducing sin into humankind. As a result, God stripped man of his access to magic, and his male descendents are forced to carry the shame of his sin throughout their lives by performing penance until they can be redeemed in the hereafter. Women remained able to utilize magic. Magic is the basis of technology and used in everyday life. Magi tech is used by everyone, but only women can create it. They do not experience pain during birth, and it is described as an almost euphoric process.

This myth is meant to explain the dominance of women in this world. Having access to magic is a sign of gods favor. Being stripped of magic is not a "noticeable" in the same way that periods or pain in childbirth are, seeing as those can be seen by the populace. What is the best way to make this punishment for males more "visual"?

Comment: Not from the tree of _life_ but from the tree of _knowledge_. They were expelled from Paradise because having eaten the fruit of the tree of knowledge there was a risk that by eating also the fruit of the tree of life they would become gods.

Comment: I don't think answer that isn't just a personal opinion is possible.

Comment: Well, if in your story god favors women, you should probably use she and not he. Then, your story is focused on Jewish "mithology" passed down to Christianity via the Bible. In such mithology the creative power belongs only to the deity. Therefore it would be safer to have the hability of creating new life with no pain as sign of favour from god.

Comment: I find your binary definition of gender offensive

Comment: @Fl.pf. what else is there to make it non-binary?

Comment: @Fl.pf. try to complain to Catholic Church - unless they will rewrite Bible, all works based on it will have to use binary definition, too. Especially with creation myths.

Comment: I see no rational reason to ever punish anybody for something over which they had no control whatsoever; by choosing it or choosing against it, taking an action or refusing to take one, advocating for it or advocating against it. Since the punishment in question will be a completely irrationally imposed burden, so is any justification of it. Which makes this not just primarily opinion-based but 100% opinion based, and any answer is an exercise in sophistry. This question deserves to be closed.

Comment: @Fl.pf. For all you know, he could have a story featuring intersexed people accessing magic in ways unexplained by the [neolithic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolithic) fable.  Don’t be offended that every description of human dimorphism doesn’t have an asterisk footnote after the *di-*.

Comment: @Amadeus Your opinion of Biblical creation myths is clouding your reason. Since the OP is building a world where an alternative version of the expulsion from Eden exists. Answering this question requires the application of logic, commonsense and reason. The fact that this myth is irrational is irrelevant.

Comment: Many of the commentators to this question need to eat the fruit of the Tree of Knowledge. Perhaps it would be nice to *actually* think about how to answer the question instead of getting your knickers in a knot about nitpicking trivia.

Comment: @a4android You are entitled to your opinion. Oh wait, I meant I am entitled to my opinion: That any answer to this question is necessarily an opinion!

Comment: @Amadeus Some prefer reasoned argument and discourse to making assertions of belief. I'm sure you do too.

Comment: @a4android Yes and no. All reasoned argument and proofs ultimately depends upon axioms and truths we take as self-evident. If you do not believe in straight lines, you will not believe the sum of the interior angles of a triangle add up to 180. As Penn and Teller are quick to demonstrate, we cannot even believe our own eyes applied with our most effortful focused attention; we can still be fooled. Thus all discourse, reasoned or not, rests upon unprovable assertions. I find this aspect of religion rests upon an assertion of truth that directly contradicts my other axiomatic beliefs, as noted.

Comment: @a4android - The post and comments here treat the Christian faith in a way that is offensive to me.  The Bible's story of the fall is about God giving us a choice between Him who is the source of life and all that was good, and not-Him.  It is the opening scene in a story of a God who loves those He creates and will in the end go to the grave to prove it.  Nor does he mindlessly condemn all for the sins on one person.  The story goes on to make it clear that all fall because all make the same choice the first humans made, we all do things even we know to be wrong.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I'm sure you'll find more posts and comments that are offensive to you on this site. Welcome to the internet :)

Comment: @Erik - true that.  A good chance to thicken my skin.  And to remind me not to fall in the same error of disrespecting belief systems different from my own.

Comment: @AgapwIesu whether you consider it an error to disrespect belief systems is up to you, but seeing it as a good chance to thicken your skin is the best you can do with it.

Comment: This question significantly distorts the Judeo-Christian account of the fall (even without considering its theological meanings and wider context). Both "Man" and "Woman" are presented as having transgressed - both in different ways - both are given specific punishments ( this question makes it seem like only women were punished). Periods are also not specifically mentioned at all as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

As a creation myth it's enough for explaining the disparity between male and females and it's a great a theodicy; men screwed up so they got magically neutered, women alone aren't powerful enough to fix the mess and now everyone has to live with it. I'd add some kind of consequence for females though for not stopping the idiots when they had the chance.

You will need to decide whether *all* women will have access to magic or not, exactly what the type of modern magic is (the rituals will evolve and get optimized over the generations), etc.

This type of tale is also a great cautionary tale about misuse of magic.

It's also a nice potential plot line to create a classic male fantasy protagonist; aka. the guy with unique powers and subject to a prophecy to save the world.

---

A variant has popped up in literature in the Wheel of Time series. Men and women have different strains of magic. Men in their hubris decided to rip open the fabric of reality (literally) and in doing so unwittingly unleashed the Dark One into the world.

They patched the hole but not before the Dark One tainted male magic so that every male magician will inevitably go insane. The site of the patch also leaks evil turning the land uninhabitable.

Comment: Actually, in the wheel of time it was a woman (Lanfear) the lead investigator who opened the rift. Men's magic was tainted when they tried to seal the breach - without help from their female colleagues.

Comment: This is a commentary on the post, but doesn’t Answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that in Christianity (and, I believe, Judaism), the whole pain in childbirth thing was kind of a slap on the wrist compared to the other bit: both the man and the woman were exiled from paradise on Earth, and became unable to enter Heaven. This could be seen as a punishment, or as a consequence (the imperfect and the perfect cannot stand each other), but you might take that into account in considering the seriousness of your mytholgy's punishment.

I think it also depends on how frequently magic is used in everyday life. You've said it's very powerful, even creative, though slow to use. Do women still use magic on a daily basis to create and shape things? Are men significantly hampered by not having this ability? Childbirth is a necessary part of life (in general; of course not all women have children), yet it's painful and dangerous, even life-threatening in some cases. That's not even touching on the inconvenience of periods and the long-term effects childbirth has on a mother's body. **Loss of magic is only equivalent to difficult childbirth if not having magic is something that inconveniences, pains, or even endangers most or all men during the natural course of their life.**

Comment: Pain at childbirth as part of the punishment is just an explanation why women suffer so much giving birth while the rest of the female mammals doesn't have (normally) such a problem. Jewish people being a tribe of nomadic sepherds, they couldn't fail to notice that oddity.

Comment: A good point: difficulty in childbirth is something of a biological oddity. Superstition, explanatory myth, and theology all seem to overlap with each other a good deal.

Comment: It's the Garden of Eden they couldn't return to rather than heaven, at least in Judaism.

Comment: Men are physically dominant over women, (on average), but are magically equal, currently. You might want to consider not having much of an actual muscular difference (aside from the ones relevant to procreation) because women were rewarded with a different kind of dominance.